# Kong migration bootstrap failing [version 1.2] with cassandra db

Tags: cassandra, kong

I was using kong 0.14.1 earlier and now wanted to try out kong 1.2. I am not worried about migrating existing data.

But while trying to run `kong migrations bootstrap`, the following error is thrown.

`Error: [Cassandra error] failed to bootstrap database: [Unauthorized] User xxxxxxx has no CREATE permission on <all keyspaces> or any of its parents`

The keyspace name provided using the env variable `KONG_CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE` already exists - so kong doesn't need to create it. Not sure why this error is thrown.

Note 1: The cassandra user doesn't have permissions to create keyspaces, but has permission to create/drop tables, UDTs etc.

Note 2: Kong migration `kong migrations up` works well with version 0.14.1 using the same cassandra user.